# Screen stuck on start

Tags: fedora

Today I updated my computer to Fedora 28. Right after that every time I start my machine the start screen showing the Fedora icon remains.

Then I took to last option on (0-rescue-2d646b937ac4cd8bbdc1e26384CCC7c) 28 (Workstation edition) , now this says:

```
device descriptor read/64 error -110
SDB no catching mode found
assuming drive cache write through
etc/multipath.conf doesn't exist
you can run /sbin/mpathconf to create or modify /etc/multipath.conf
```

### My graphics hardware / kernel driver:

```
[root@dhcppc2 mc]# lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2633
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: @sourcejedi first of all, in said link I couldn't find command. One command returned [mc@dhcppc2 ~]$ (lspci -nn | grep -i audio) 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/fedora-upgrade-question-closed-as-typo                                                                @sourcejedi I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, the Fedora install guide claims that this "usually means a problem with the graphical boot sequence; to solve this issue, you must disable graphical boot.".  It is only talking about the graphical boot progress and icon - you can disable this and still use a graphical desktop like Gnome.

> https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f28/install-guide/install/Troubleshooting.html#sect-trouble-after-graphical-boot
>
> After you finish the installation and reboot your system for the first time, it is possible that the system stops responding during the graphical boot sequence, requiring a reset. In this case, the boot loader is displayed successfully, but selecting any entry and attempting to boot the system results in a halt. This usually means a problem with the graphical boot sequence; to solve this issue, you must disable graphical boot. To do this, temporarily alter the setting at boot time before changing it permanently.

In Fedora, you can do this by removing the `rhgb` boot option.  The install manual includes a comprehensive explanation of how to test this temporarily, and then change it permanently.

(The linked version involves using `su -`. If you have not set a root password, use `sudo su -` instead).

For SO policy reasons I have paste-dumped it here, but the linked version has better formatting.

---

Trouble With the Graphical Boot Sequence

After you finish the installation and reboot your system for the first time, it is possible that the system stops responding during the graphical boot sequence, requiring a reset. In this case, the boot loader is displayed successfully, but selecting any entry and attempting to boot the system results in a halt. This usually means a problem with the graphical boot sequence; to solve this issue, you must disable graphical boot. To do this, temporarily alter the setting at boot time before changing it permanently.

Disabling Graphical Boot Temporarily

1. Start your computer and wait until the boot loader menu appears. If you set your boot loader timeout period to 0, hold down the Esc key to access it.
2. When the boot loader menu appears, use your cursor keys to highlight the entry you want to boot and press the e key to edit this entry’s options.
3. In the list of options, find the kernel line - that is, the line beginning with the keyword linux (or, in some cases, linux16 or linuxefi). On this line, locate the rhgb option and delete it. The option may not be immediately visible; use the cursor keys to scroll up and down.
4. Press F10 or Ctrl+X to boot your system with the edited options.
5. If the system started successfully, you can log in normally. Then you will need to disable the graphical boot permanently - otherwise you will have to perform the previous procedure every time the system boots. To permanently change boot options, do the following.

Disabling Graphical Boot Permanently

1. Log in to the root account using the su - command:

   ```
   $ su -
   ```
2. Open the /etc/default/grub configuration file using a plain text editor such as vim.
3. Within the grub file, locate the line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. The line should look similar to the following:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 vconsole.keymap=us $([ -x /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param ] && /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param || :) rd.luks=0 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=vg_rhel/swap rhgb quiet"
   ```

   On this line, delete the rhgb option.
4. Save the edited configuration file.
5. Refresh the boot loader configuration by executing the following command:

   ```
   # grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
   ```

After you finish this procedure, you can reboot your computer. Fedora will not use the graphical boot sequence any more. If you wish to enable graphical boot, follow the same procedure, add the rhgb option to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line in the /etc/default/grub file and refresh the boot loader configuration again using the grub2-mkconfig command.

See the Fedora System Administrator’s Guide, available at http://docs.fedoraproject.org/, for more information about working with the GRUB2 boot loader.